# Программа для самоконтроля при работе

Tags: linux, debian, поиск-программ

Здравствуйте. Я начинающий программист и работаю с плавающим графиком, у меня есть возможность работать как в офисе, так и дома, главное, что бы работа была сделана.

Меня интересуют программы (в частности на Debian), которые помогут не отвлекаться от работы, но и напоминала бы о перерывах от работы. Желательно, что бы в программе была возможность ввода задач (на день, неделю) и указания примерного времени на их выполнения.

Кто знает подобные программы или может дополнения в браузеры?

Просмотренные программы:

- [EyeLeo](http://eyeleo.com/) - напоминалка о перерыве.
- [Workrave](http://www.workrave.org/) - тоже напоминалка о перерыве.
- [Motivate Clock](http://motivateclock.org/) - очень понравилась, но она для Windows. Есть ли подобное или она же на Debian?
- [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) - подробный отслеживатель времени, но только не для Linux.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он относится не к разработке, а к поиску готовых программ

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [Pomodoro](http://gnomepomodoro.org/) - ставить себе установку, что следующие 25 минут занимаюсь работой и ни на что не отвлекаюсь, и после напоминать или блокировать экран для отдыха. В течении рабочего дня стремиться поработать 3 Pomodoro и с каждым днем стараться проработать больше предыдущего дня. [Статья](http://open-life.org/blog/1779.html) про разные варианты помидорок на Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Я [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/) использую, там подробное логирование своего времени - по программам, сайтам, но без напоминалок и списка дел

Comment: RescueTime (русская версия) предназначена для Windows. У меня разновидность Linux.